# ¿Como recorrer esta lista?

Tags: c#, linq, lista, reflection

Tengo una lista con esta estructura llamada `InputText`:

[image: Imagen con el contenido de la lista]

La cual intento recorrer con este código:

```
  public  void  MoveTo <T> ( Page pag , Object obj) 
    {

        var InputText = pag.ChildControls().OfType<T>().ToList();//.AsQueryable().Select("new(ID, SelectedValue)"); 
        var _r = InputText.AsQueryable().OrderBy("ID").Select("new(ID)").GetEnumerator();
        var queryable = InputText.AsQueryable();//.AsEnumerable();

        try
        {
            foreach (var list in InputText)
            {
                try
                {
                    var prop = InputText.First().GetType().GetProperty("ID", BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    var reti = queryable.Select(p => prop.GetValue(p).ToString()).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();              
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
                try
                {
                    /*  PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(list.ID.ToString().TrimStart(new char[] { 'v', 'f' }));
                      Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;
                      object safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
                      property.SetValue(obj, safeValue, null);*/
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception es) { }
    }
```

Cómo puedo obtener cada valor por separado?

Bien, hasta ahora he intentado con:

- LinQ
- Reflection.

Cuando intento recorrer la lista, trato de recuperar el valor de la propiedad `name`.

[image: Foreach utilizado para recorrer la lista]

Y obtengo este error:

[image: Error obtenido: "Object doesn't match target type."]

No puedo usar LinQ, porque al parecer mi lista no es de tipo `IEnumerable`, he intentado el cast pero no lo he logrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que genera mi lista, básicamente recorro una página `asp`, para recuperar todos los `DropDownList` y me los devuelve en una lista:

```
       public static IEnumerable<Control> MyChildControls(this Control control, Func<Control, bool> selector)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<IEnumerator<Control>>();

        stack.Push(control.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => selector(c)).GetEnumerator());

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var en = stack.Peek();
            if (en.MoveNext())
            {
                var item = en.Current;
                yield return item;

                if (item.HasControls())
                {
                    stack.Push(item.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(c => selector(c)).GetEnumerator());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stack.Pop();
            }
        }
    }
```

**La última versión de mi código me acerco bastante. Sin embargo, necesitaría recuperar un `ID` en cada interaccion del `foreach`.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Emerson. Por favor indica qué has probado hasta ahora y los errores concretos para que podamos ayudarte con ellos. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info en como mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo (por que tienes la tag [tag:reflection]?)

Comment: Escribe esos intentos que has hecho, o al menos el último. Así se podrán hacer sugerencias

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado indicando donde falla o el porqué no te funciona. Como te ha dicho el compañero @lois6b, deberías mirar [ask] y rehacer tu pregunta de acuerdo a las normas del sitio.

Comment: Edito para ampliar...

Comment: Pon la definición de tu lista

Comment: ¿Puedes poner también qué es "InputText"?

Comment: InputText es el nombre de la lista resultante que aparece al inicio de la pregunta

Comment: Sí, ¿pero es una lista de qué? ¿Podrías poner la definición o cómo la cargas?

Comment: Primero, debes añadir el codigo como texto, no como capturas de imagen. Segundo, necesitamos la definicion de la lista.

Comment: Es una lista de comboboxes, por cierto?

Comment: Asi es es una lista de dropdownlist...

Comment: En ese caso, en tu foreach deberas hacer algo como `foreach( var list in InputText) { int indice = list.SelectedIndex;` No das informacion de la estructura, asi que no te puedo decir mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void MoveTo<T>(Page pag ,Object obj)
{
  var InputText = pag.ChildControls().OfType<T>().ToList();

  foreach(var value in InputText)
  {
    var name = value.GetProperty("ID").GetValue(value);
  }

}
```

no entendí a que valor querías obtener en la propiedad reti